# C# : Power Operator not available

Tags: c#

Do we have predefined Power Operator in C#?

When I try with ^ Operator, It is taking exclusive-or operation.

Is there any way to include the Pow Operator other than Math Library?

Comment: Power of this multiplication for n times. If you don't want to use Math write one yourself.

Comment: @NathanCooper What about `2**1.5`?

Comment: There is no `**` operator in C#

Comment: @Rik Indeed. That's pretty much the crux of the question isn't it? My comment to Nathan is to point out that repeated multiplication only works for integer exponents.

Comment: @David Heffernan. Yes good point, but I'm not going to ask someone to self-implement ^ for Doubles (int is easy, I think it's a two line recursive method, doubles would be a series expansion) Use Math.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built in power operator similar to that found in Fortran, Python etc.

- For floating operands you should use `Math.Pow`.
- For efficient exponentiation of integer operands there is nothing included in the framework. Instead you can roll your own. For example: [How do you do *integer* exponentiation in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383587/how-do-you-do-integer-exponentiation-in-c)