# C# Remainder and Pow giving weird results

Tags: c#

I'm trying to encode a `byte[]` as `base[whatever]`. It's working in most cases but not all.
I can simplify the problem to:

```cs
    private void TestDigits()
    {
        ulong number = 15768074845946621;
        ulong l = number;
        uint b = 63;
        List<int> digits = new List<int>();
        while (l >= b)
        {
            digits.Add((int)(l % b));
            l = l / b;
        }
        if (l > 0) { digits.Add((int)l); }

        ulong r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count; i++)
        {
            ulong pow = (ulong)Math.Pow(b, i);
            r += (ulong)digits[i] * pow;
        }

        if (r != number) throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("number:\"{0}\" does not match r:\"{1}\".", number, r));
    }
```

I think, `r` should be the same as `number`?
The code works if `b` is 62 or `number` is something smaller like 1000.
Any idea why, in this case, `r` is not the same as `number`?

In most cases, where it's wrong, `r` is 1 greater than `number`, so assuming it's a rounding error somewhere, but I cannot spot where.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - thanks! If I replace Math.Pow with my own version it works! I've been trying to fix that for hours - never thought to look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RobertHarvey got it!
Was `Math.Pow` not being precise enough.

```cs
    private void TestDigits()
    {
        ulong number = 15768074845946621;
        ulong l = number;
        uint b = 62;
        List<int> digits = new List<int>();
        while (l >= b)
        {
            digits.Add((int)(l % b));
            l = l / b;
        }
        if (l > 0) { digits.Add((int)l); }

        ulong r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count; i++)
        {
            ulong pow = MathPow(b, i);//(ulong)Math.Pow(b, i);
            r += (ulong)digits[i] * pow;
        }

        if (r != number) throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("number:\"{0}\" does not match r:\"{1}\".", number, r));
    }
    private ulong MathPow(uint b, int i)
    {
        ulong returnValue = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            returnValue *= b;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: As you're performing integer power ops, why use `Math.Pow` here at all? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383587/how-do-you-do-integer-exponentiation-in-c